# Detailed Materials on Sunflowers

Tags: co.combinatorics, survey

Jukna's book *Extremal Combinatorics* explains basic results about sunflowers.  Is there a more thorough survey of various sunflower results?

Comment: "[On Sunflowers and Matrix Multiplication](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~umans/papers/ASU11-final.pdf)". P.S. in order to avoid trivial answers (like mine :-) you should write in your question a list of papers/results you already have/know ...

Comment: its hard to beat jukna ("the surveyor") for surveys! fyi there are some new tighter ("quasi-")sunflower thms in b.rossmans [Phd thesis](http://www.mit.edu/~brossman/mit-thesis.pdf) & related paper

Comment: also apparently closely related, the [erdos-ko-rado thm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem), proof eg [here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/comb/ekr.pdf)

Comment: [the Hilton-Milner theorem](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_frankl_nontrivial-intersecting.pdf) complements EKR and shows that the maximum size of an intersecting family is only attained by the trivial sunflower with a single element in the common intersection