# Does this problem have a name? Finding a subset intersecting all subsets of a family

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am pretty sure this problem has a name, or it can be reworded so it does. We are given a set $X$ and a family $\mathcal F$ of subsets of $X$, the problem is to find a subset $B$ such that $B\cap A\neq \emptyset$ for all $A\in \mathcal F$.

Comment: [MINIMUM HITTING SET](http://www.nada.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node149.html) (NP-complete)

Comment: Thank you very much, was this question on topic here, or was it bad?

Comment: What if the problem is to count the number of minimum hitting sets?

Comment: What if the problem is to count the number of hitting sets? Even those which ar not minimum?

Comment: Remember that the decision version is "Is there a hitting set with no more than $k$ elements?" (where $k$ is part of the input). If you want to count them, you probably "hit" a #P-complete problem (the equivalent MINIMUM SET COVER is #P-complete) .

Comment: Thanks, do you know the complexity class when we want to count all hitting sets? Not just the minimum ones?

Comment: The problem remains in #P if you set $k= |X|$ (i.e. you want to count all the possible hitting sets).

Comment: what do you mean by "subset B"? of X? it seems maybe ambiguously stated. this might be a variant of the [sunflower problem](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14558/the-state-of-art-for-sunflower-system) & was studied up to decades ago by erdos & shows up in some deep complexity theory proofs eg by razborov on monotone circuit lower bounds etc. the separate sets are known as the "petals" and the intersecting set is known as the "core".